# System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext.DrawImage() showing white pixels instead of black in semi-transparent areas like shadows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, drawing, system.windows.media

I have a WPF Button subclass that overrides OnRender() to draw one of several bitmaps depending on the current state. The simplified (1-bitmap) code is shown below...

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext context)
    {
        context.DrawImage(_MyBitmapSource, new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
    }
```

**The semitransparent black pixels of the shadows in each bitmap incorrectly render as semitransparent white.**

Likewise if I set one of these images as the Background brush the same thing happens.

For Image controls setting the same image to Source looks correct, so I know WPF is able to draw the shadows correctly. I'm obviously missing something — possibly something else that needs to be set in OnRender() before the call to DrawImage().

There's nothing special about the PNG images. Just to be certain that wasn't the problem I downloaded a few PNGs from images.google.com and they all had the same issue.

Comment: The "obvious" way to do this sort of thing would be using templating and a button templated as an image. Then switch out the imagesource depending on whatever your criteria are. Because of that I have never overridden onrender of a button. Maybe you could consider that sort of approach or supply code reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I get the same result. I put an Image control in the control template of the button, set its Source, and removed the OnRender() override. Still getting semitransparent white pixels in the shadow where semitransparent black pixels should be.

Comment: Does just an image using your png give this unexpected result?

Comment: Hang on... nevermind. There was something wrong with the surrounding xaml. Your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks, @Andy!

Comment: When you get a chance, copy your answer to an official answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other frameworks, events such as Paint or Render are usually used to change look of controls.

WPF has lookless controls - you can template a wpf control to be just about anything you can imagine. This is rather mind numbing, extremely powerful and makes some things way easier than they would be in those other frameworks.

Hence the "conventional" wpf approach to creating an image that has the behaviour of a  button is just to set the template of a button to an image. You can then set imagessource by code or markup. Markkup is usually preferred by WPF developers and you have multiple options including datatriggers, triggers, templating and visual states.

Other benefits of this approach are that markup allows you to get an immediate idea of what will happen and you can fairly easily simplify it right down for any trouble shooting.

Comment: For future readers who might not spot @Andy's specific suggestion in the comments above, I added an Image control tag between the <ControlTemplate></ControlTemplate> tags of the button. Once I cleaned up some problems in the encapsulating xaml, his suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks again, Andy.